# Mongoose Model.create() not saving document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I'm working on console CRUD app using: Node, Mongo, Mongoose, commander.js, and inquirer.js.

In app.js, `addItem()` is a function that returns Model.create({obj}), which according to the Mongoose docs, should return a promise. However, when I try to log the resp in the next `then()` I get no output. This was working fine before with a different model, but now not so much. I have a feeling `create()` isn't working (I know it's not, because no collection is created in the db), but I can't even figure out how to log the error. I've been stuck on this for a day or two and it doesn't seem like any one else has had this issue; or at least I don't know how to frame the problem correctly.

**app.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise; 
const program = require('commander');
const { prompt } = require('inquirer');
const {addItem, getItem, removeItem, makeArray} = require('./logic.js');
const {itemTypeQuestion, papyriQuestions, lampQuestions} = require('./questions');

const typeQuestions = (type) => {
    if(type === 'papyrus') {
        return prompt(papyriQuestions).then(resp => {resp.item_type = type; return resp})
    } else if (type === 'lamp') {
        return prompt(lampQuestions).then(resp => {resp.item_type = type; return resp})
    }
}

program
    .command('addItem')
    .alias('a')
    .description('Add an item')
    .action( () => {
        prompt(itemTypeQuestion)
        .then(resp => typeQuestions(resp.item_type))
        .then(answers => makeArray(answers, "more_ids", "other_ids", ", ") )
        .then(resp => addItem(resp))
        .then(resp => console.info(resp))
        .then(mongoose.disconnect())
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
            mongoose.disconnect();
        })
    } )
```

**logic.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/museum_catalog', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const {Papyrus, Lamp} = require('./schema.js');

/**
* @function  [addItem]
* @returns {Promise} Promise
*/
const addItem = (item) => {
    if (item.item_type === 'papyrus') {
        return Papyrus.create(item)
    } else if (item.item_type === 'lamp') {
        return Lamp.create(item)
    } 
}
const makeArray = (input, field, newKey, separator) => {
    input[newKey] = [];
    if (input[field] != 0) {
        input[field].split(separator).forEach(element => {
            input[newKey].push(element)
        });
    }
    return input;
}

module.exports = {addItem, getItem, removeItem, makeArray}
```

**schema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-extend-schema
function extendSchema (Schema, definition, options) {
    return new mongoose.Schema(
      Object.assign({}, Schema.obj, definition),
      options
    );
  }


// Define Item schema
const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    primary_id: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, unique: true, trim: true, index: true},
    other_ids: [],
    item_type: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, trim: true},
    description: {type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true},
    date_created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    hidden: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    height: Number,
    width: Number
})

// Papyrus schema & model
const papyrusSchema = extendSchema(itemSchema, {
    item_type: {type: String, default: 'papyrus', lowercase: true},
    language: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, trim: true},
});

const Papyrus = mongoose.model('papyrus', papyrusSchema);

// Lamp schema & model
const lampSchema = extendSchema(itemSchema, {
    item_type: {type: String, default: 'lamp', lowercase: true},
    isInscription: Boolean,
    language: {type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true},
})
const Lamp = mongoose.model('lamps', lampSchema);

module.exports = {Papyrus, Lamp};
```

Perhaps I'm not understanding Promises correctly or how Mongoose is working. Also, any general feedback on other things is always welcomed

*EDIT - FIXED 8/18/18
In **schema.js** I added

```
const testItem = { primary_id: 'Je.41',
more_ids: 'C90',
description: 'test',
height: '12',
width: '12',
hidden: false,
language: 'test',
item_type: 'papyrus',
other_ids: [ 'C90' ] }
Papyrus.create(testItem).then(resp => {console.log(resp)}).catch(e => {console.error(e)})
```

to have it create an item on startup and received this error:

```
MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
```

Apparently, the the app was disconnecting too soon. In **app.js** I changed `.then(mongoose.disconnect())` > `.then(resp => mongoose.disconnect())` and it worked.

I'm still not sure

1. Why the errors never logged?
2. Since `disconnect()` was in a `then()` shouldn't it have waited?

Still trying to figure out these promises.

Comment: Can you please provide some console output to allow us to help you better?

Comment: `.then(resp => console.info(resp))` logs nothing (not even undefined, it just doesn't run). I expect something like: `{primary_id: 'some id', item_type: 'papyrus', ...}`

Comment: You can log error by adding a `catch` clause. `Papyrus.create(item).catch(e =>{ console.log(e); })` and `Lamp.create(item).catch(e =>{ console.log(e); })`. Hope it helps

Comment: Tried that. No error is ever logged.